# Pass regex to graphQL query using axios

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, foreach, graphql

I have a graphQL mutation that I am running using axios inside of a forEach loop. One of the values I am passing is a regex rule as a string but when I run my function, I get the following errors when I pass values like `^(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F\/\.\_\-]+?$`

```
[
  {
    message: 'Parse error on "\\"" (error) at [13, 32]',
    locations: [ [Object] ]
  }
]

[
  {
    message: 'Parse error on "^" (error) at [13, 34]',
    locations: [ [Object] ]
  }
]


[
  {
    message: 'Parse error on "[" (LBRACKET) at [13, 34]',
    locations: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
```

My code:

```
const createMut = (id, res) => `
    mutation {
        createField(input: {
            id: "${id}",
            label: "${res.label}",
            custom_validation: "${res.custom_validation}",
            }) {
            table_field {
              id
              label
            }
        }
    }
`;

const myFunc = (id, result) => {
    result.data.forEach(d => {
        axiosFunc({ query: create_fields(id, d) }).then((response) => response);
    });
}
```

`d.custom_validation` inside of result is set to values like `^(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F\/\.\_\-]+?$` or `^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$` format. But when I call my function, I am getting the errors mentioned above. How do I send a regex value to a graphQL mutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query `variables` instead of trying to inject the variables directly into the query:

```
const query = "mutation myMutation($id: ID!, $label: String, $custom_validation: String) {
  createField(input: {
    id: $id,
    label: $label,
    custom_validation: $custom_validation,
  }) {
    table_field {
      id
      label
    }
  }
}";

const myFunc = (id, result) => {
  result.data.forEach(({ label, custom_validation }) => {
    const variables = { id, label, custom_validation };
    axiosFunc({ query, variables }).then((response) => response);
  });
}
```

If `custom_validation` is a javascript regex object instead of a string then you'll need to convert it to a string.

```
const variables = { id, label, custom_validation: custom_validation.toString() };
```